# convert interactive python commands to py file commands

Tags: python, regex

Below are the commands & the corresponding output from a pyspark-shell.
I'm trying to separate the commands alone and copy it to a new file.

```
>>> m=[10,20,30,40,50]
>>> print(m)
[10, 20, 30, 40, 50]
>>> print(type(m))
<class 'list'>
>>> data=[[m]]
>>> header=["num"]
>>> df=spark.createDataFrame(data,header)
>>> df.show(truncate=False)
+--------------------+
|num                 |
+--------------------+
|[10, 20, 30, 40, 50]|
+--------------------+

>>> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- num: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: long (containsNull = true)

>>> (spark.sql("select num, explode(num) x from numbers")
... .show(truncate=False))
+--------------------+---+
|num                 |x  |
+--------------------+---+
|[10, 20, 30, 40, 50]|10 |
|[10, 20, 30, 40, 50]|20 |
|[10, 20, 30, 40, 50]|30 |
|[10, 20, 30, 40, 50]|40 |
|[10, 20, 30, 40, 50]|50 |
+--------------------+---+

>>> spark.sql(""" select num,
... explode(num) x from numbers
... """)
DataFrame[num: array<bigint>, x: bigint]
>>> 

>>> def run(file):
...     exec(open(file).read())
... 
>>>
```

I had partial success with the below perl command,

```
perl -ne ' { /^>>>(.*)/ && print "$1\n" } ' py_commands.txt
```

but there are corner cases
where the python commands extend more than one line when "()" or triple quotes
""" is used.

Required output:

```
m=[10,20,30,40,50]
print(m)
print(type(m))
data=[[m]]
header=["num"]
df=spark.createDataFrame(data,header)
df.show(truncate=False)
df.printSchema()
(spark.sql("select num, explode(num) x from numbers")
     .show(truncate=False))
spark.sql(""" select num,
     explode(num) x from numbers
    """)
def run(file):
    exec(open(file).read())
```

Comment: why don't you use an OR selector that matches lines beginning with `>>> ` or `... ` (notice the whitespace in the end)? also, i wouldn't care about indenting lines that start by `... `. interesting regex use case

Comment: @arthursimas "_i wouldn't care about indenting lines_"  -- Why not? it'd be messy to read without that.  We always want indentation so why not have it?

Comment: @zdim i think i have expressed myself wrongly. i meant the regular expression shouldn't care about indenting or not lines starting by `... `, instead, the code should be already indented. i thought about that because of the required output example provided, that adds indentation

Comment: FYI, if you were to use [IPython](https://ipython.org/), it serves this with [%history](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-history) (or %hist as a shorthand)

Answer (score 3):

For multiline statements the extension lines start with `...`, just as statements start with `>>>`

```
perl -wnE'/^(?:>>>|(\.\.\.))\s+(.+)/ and say +($1? "\t$2" : $2)' py_session.txt
```

I add a tab to start continuation lines, the ones starting with `...`, by testing whether that was captured in the alternation (the `$1` is taken for that pair of parens, either filled or left `undef`).

If that's not needed the thing simplifies a lot, to just

```
perl -wnE'/^(?:>>>|\.\.\.)[ ](.+)/ and say $1' file
```

This differs with respect to mutliple indentation levels in input, see comments.

---

- Tested with little other than the shown sample (and it behaves as expected for it)
- Doesn't reproduce empty lines, following "*required output*"; for those change `(.+)` to `(.*)`
- The indentation added for continuation lines does not take into account a possibly existing indentation level in a file into which this output would go.
- There can be multiply-intended input, where indentation matters: an `if ():` statement inside a `def func():` for example.  That is parsed into correct python programs in my simple tests, *when redirected to a file*. Printing it to screen converts `\t` characters to the corresponding number of spaces, what may end up *without* any indentation where needed, resulting in invalid programs.
- Another option is to indeed not indent lines with `...`, and capture (all but one!) leading spaces with the command text to be reproduced, in the second example above. I haven't tested this much with more complex indentation cases.

To add, I would expect that one can come up with more complex code that would not be parsed into correct python programs with these simple-minded approaches.

Comment: I think, it's just ok for now.. doing its job..well done!

Comment: I'm also wondering, how could I do an inverse of this?..to get the command outputs alone?..

Comment: @stack0114106 "_how could I do an inverse of this_" -- yeah, I thought that you may want that.  Should be easy: if the regex didn't match then the line is a part of command's output! So store it in a separate structure.  (Could be a hash where you first capture commands and then their output, but that would need a bit more since some cmds don't produce output.)  Whichever way you sort it, that should go to a different file -- or, prepend a `#` and print it out along with commands themselves, so as comments.   Then this program should go to a file, not as a command-line one ("one-liner")

Comment: @stack0114106  "_how could I do an inverse of this ... Should be easy_"  -- Tested, yes it works: instead of `/.../ and say...` do `if (/.../) { say ... } else { $o .= $_ };` So what you have now goes inside `if` and `else` you add it to `$o`.  Then at the end print `$o`, by adding `END { say $o }` to the end.  This is the simplest way, just to collect and print all of it.  If you want outputs associated with commands that would take a little more

Comment: @stack0114106 Altogether `perl -wnE'if (/.../) { say ... } else { $o .= $_ };  END { say "\n===\n\n $o" }'`  Or, add `#` so it can go directly into a program: `... else { $o .= "# $_" }`

Comment: @stack0114106 Edited with comments that may matter for input (code) with multiple indentation levels

Answer (score 2):

The Python REPL terminal uses `>>>`  and `...`  as line starts to indicate lines that has commands. So, your expression should contain not only `>>>` , but also `...` .

In this case, it would be:

```bash
perl -ne ' { /^(>>>|\.\.\.) (.*)/ && print "$2\n" } ' py_commands.txt
```